# FileTransfer error code 1, Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, ibm-mobilefirst

I have build the WindowsPhone8.1 application using MobileFirst v7.0. I have used the FileTransfer phonegap plugin for transferring file to server.

While invoking upload method of FileTransfer plugin, I got the following error.

```
failure : {"code":1,"source":"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10080/FileUploadServlet/","target":"C:\\Data\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Non-Production Errors.txt","http_status":null,"body":null,"exception":null}
```

For picking up file location, I have used the native code to open the file picker and then get the location of File.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Note: I have picked the file from phone -> documents folder.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Phone, `FileTransfer` only able to access the application storage and not the phone and sd card storage.

So, location picked by file using Native `FilePicker` is not known to `FileTransfer` and it is throwing **FileNotFoundError**.

As an work around I have copied the file picker by `FilePicker` to application storage and then transferred it using `FileTransfer`.